# When I start my rabbitmq server it gets stuck on "Starting broker... completed with 9 plugins"

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rabbitmq

The rabbitmq-server file lives inside `/usr/local/sbin`as it should. So I change directory to `sbin`, write rabbitmq-server in my terminal and it successfully launches and shows these lines in the terminal: [image]

But it gets stuck on the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal if you run `rabbitmq-server`.

Use `rabbitmq-server -detached` to run in background.